# Zip codes in Radius Google Map

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, mapping, zipcode

Hope someone can advise,

I would like to be able to use google map API to find all Zip codes/cities with x Miles of a point.

Has anyone done such a thing with google map or maybe some other type of service.

Would love to know if so how you have achieved it !

Thank you if you can advise.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing in the Google Maps API that can help with that, and I've never heard of any such service that could be mashed up with a Google Map.

What you could do is obtain a list of the locations of all the zip codes. Do a web search for [free zip code database] there are lots of them out there. Put it on your server then write your own server script to search it.

Comment: -1 Apparently there is: http://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm - Does exactly that.

Comment: This answer was correct at the time of writing. Version info of 'Find ZIP Codes Inside a Radius' shows `Version 1 (10/02/2010) - Initial Version` and that is Februar 2010.